# How to register a click event on a list of input (radio button?)

Tags: javascript, jquery

My requirement is that I can execute some javascript code when the user clicks any of the radio buttons on my webapp.

Currently, I am struggling to register a click event on the list of input.

I have the following code in my app currently just to visualize what the structure of the radio buttons are:

```
var excardsRadio = $("input[id^='card-radiobutton']");
```

Which prints:

```
[input#card-radiobutton-0, input#card-radiobutton-1, prevObject: init(1), context: document, selector: "input[id^='card-radiobutton']"]
```

So now essentially I am trying to register the same click function on all of these inputs (`card-radiobutton-0` and `card-radiobutton-2`), where the click function for now would just do a console log that something happened.

Does anyone have any tips or guide to help with what Im trying to accomplish here?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: `excardsRadio.click(function() { /* do something here... */ });` I would suggest you use a common class on the elements though, instead of incremental `id`

Comment: What i am trying to accomplish is that i can run a function whenever a user selects any of the radio buttons on my page.

Comment: please check my answer it might help you bro..

Answer (score 0):

As @Rory commented, you should use a common class on the elements.

```
 $(document).on('click', '.youradioclass', yourfunction);
```

.

```
function yourfunction(){

   your javascript code here...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can handle radio event in entire page by using this code.

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click', function(){alert("working");});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click here to display alert
<input type="radio"/>
<input type="radio"/>
<input type="radio"/>
```